# php not moving uploaded file on iis

Tags: php, iis

iis_iusrs has read and write in the uploads dir "c:\temp" and in the destination folder "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\uploads".

After my script runs a tmp file is created. in the c:\temp dir however the file is not moved. When it runs on chrome it says "Success".

```
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 112097152) {
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true) {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
 }
    ?>
<html>
 <body>

  <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "image" />
     <input type = "submit"/>

     <ul>
        <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
        <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
        <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
         </ul>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see the error and use `$result = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);` to see result of operation.

Comment: appearently I don't have the permissions set correctly.                                       rning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\temp\phpCFFB.tmp' to 'uploads/1.jpg' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.php on line 38 Thanks for your help

Comment: iis_iusrs has read and write access to the root directory. this is my first time working with iis.

Comment: I had to give permissions Iusr